# Can a subordinate clause have two functions at the same time?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Please consider the following example:

> What can we do that is more important than choosing the men and women who serve us by running our government?

The that-clause looks like a relative clause to me. It modifies the word "what" (or the answer to it). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Could we make a slight rewording to make the same clause function as a complement?

If I'm getting it all wrong, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

> What can we do **that is more important than choosing the men and women
>   who serve us by running our government?**

You're right, the portion in bold is a relative clause.

> that is more important than choosing the men and women who serve us by
>   running our government?

This cannot be a complement because no linking verb could directly precede it.  You could not write, "What is that is more important than choosing the men..."

> that is **more important than choosing the men and women who serve us by
>   running our government**?

The portion in bold is the complement of the subject "that" of the relative clause.

> What is **more important than choosing the men and women
>   who serve us by running our government**?

However, if by "slight rewording" includes deleting the subject "that" from the relative clause, then it can become a complement as shown here in bold, which is the same complement as further up in the relative clause further up.  It simply moves from being a complement of a relative clause to being a complement of a sentence.